# ExpandableListView doesn't expand when CheckedView change with LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have row for expandable list

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSelectHandleLeft="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
    </CheckedTextView>

<!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        style="@style/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        style="@style/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/expanded_row_points"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>-->
```

When I changed CheckedTextView (commented checkedview and uncomment linearlayout) with LinearLayout commented below list doesn't expand, when is CheckedView is uncommented and LinearLayout commented it doesn't fire event( doesn't expand).
What is a problem, does anyone hav a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to follow your question but if you are using the linearlayout as the cell layout this:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

is probably overriding the default click handling. Since the cell layout is consuming the click the listview never knows to expand.